# Powershell clean String data using words in a defined list

Tags: powershell

```
$ignoreList =  @("muzi","puzi")

$data = "
blabla aa 11
blabla bb 22
muzi aa 20
muzi bb aa
aaa aa 41
blabla aa 20
puzi aa 11
puzi bb 32
puzi cc 44"
```

i need to create new data where it hold all the data except the onces that are also in the ignore list

```
#i can iterate the list and run a loop, get $str to be the item in the list and 
#and then save each time
$data | where-object {$_ -notlike $str}
```

I figure there's some better option than iterating the list abd savubg each time

Comment: `$ignoreList.ForEach{ $Data = $Data -Replace $_ }; $Data`

Comment: [1] you are sending the `$Data` thru as one multi-line string. is that what you want?  or do you want to process each line? ///// [2] do you want to remove the words ... or the lines that contain the words? ///// [3] try using `-replace` and a regex OR pattern. something like `ThingOne|2ndThing|YetAnotherThing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-like` can only handle *one* pattern ([wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) expression) at the time.

To **match against *multiple* patterns in a single operation**, you have two options:

- Use the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based **[`-notmatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator** with an **alternation expression (`|`)**, which requires you to *escape* the ignore words with `[regex]::Escape()` in order for them to be used *verbatim* as part of the regex (not strictly necessary with your specific search terms, so in this simple case you could get away with `'^(?:{0})' -f ($ignoreList -join '|')`); use of a regex also allows you to assert that each ignore word must be found at the *start* of each string (`^`):

```sh
$ignoreList =  @("muzi","puzi")

# Create an *array* of sample lines.
$data = @'
blabla aa 11
blabla bb 22
muzi aa 20
muzi bb aa
aaa aa 41
blabla aa 20
puzi aa 11
puzi bb 32
puzi cc 44"
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# The programmatically created regex results in:
#    '^(?:muzi|puzi)'
# The ?: part isn't strictly necessary, but makes the (...) group
# non-capturing, which prevents unnecessary work.
$data -notmatch ('^(?:{0})' -f ($ignoreList.ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'))
```

- Use the **[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) cmdlet with multiple patterns** (though you may use a single one with alternation too), which may be *literal* search terms if you add `-SimpleMatch`. This approach is simpler, but slower, due to use of the pipeline:

```sh
# Note the need to use (...).Line to extract the matching strings.
# In PowerShell (Core) 7+ you could use -Raw instead.
($data | Select-String -Pattern $ignoreList -SimpleMatch -NotMatch).Line
```